# Give a JavaScript function the event parameter

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dom-events

I have the following method I want to run on a `onclick` event:

```
function dostuff(evt) {
       var currentTarget = evt.currentTarget;
       // do more stuff
    }
```

On my link, I add the `onclick` event the following way:

```
 link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "dostuff()");
```

However, then the `evt` parameter is null in my above example. I want to parse the click event to the JavaScript function, so I can get the `currentTarget`, `srcElement` etc.

How do I add that on my `onclick` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `onclick` attribute like this:

```
link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "dostuff.call(this, event)");
```

---

- `this` in the function will be the bound element,
- the `event` object will be passed along
- it works both in standards browsers as well as IE8 and lower *(including the event object being passed)*

Answer (score 0):

Parantheses are extra:

```
link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "dostuff");
```

You are assigning the return value of `"dostuff"` to the `"onclick" event instead of assigning the pointer to the function.

Also instead of using `"evt"` use `"event"` keyword as it should be. Use the `"srcElement"` property to access the element.

```
function dostuff() {

    var currentElement = event.srcElement;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Code-behind:

```
HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return handleHyperLinkClick(this);");
```

Aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function handleHyperLinkClick(hyperlink) {

            return confirm("Do you want to navigate to " + hyperlink.href + " ?");
        }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!